# Improve regular expression for URL

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regular expression for URL

```
"^(((https?|ftp|file|)://)|(www))[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]$"
```

Almost all my test scenarios works except one

```
"www.foo" <---WRONG this url it's not valid for my system
"www.foo.com" <--- valid
"www.blah.net" <--- valid
"http://blah.com" <--- valid
"https://blah.com" <--- valid
```

Does anybody could help me to improve my regular expression

Comment: what are the valid tldns for your system?

Comment: `.com` `.net` `.com.ve` `.org` `.gob` `.edu`, there just a few but could be more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend this.

`www.foo` for example could be a valid local host name.

Regardless of that. Let `System.Uri` do the hard work and access the various parts via its numerous properties

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: Although, `www` would be the host and `foo` would be the domain.

Comment: I tried same tricks with regex and finally still using Uri :)

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Even though I didn't think that far, the statement is not correct in this context. `Uri` doesn't differentiate this. Also, it doesn't make much sense to look at both, since it tells you nothing about the validity of the domain - be it a top-level or an ordinary one. A look-up if the address is local might tell you more. `CheckHostName` of `Uri` might be of some help, too - I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions  for every valid URL

```
<?php 

function validateURL($val) {
  $pattern_1 = "/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i";
  $pattern_2 = "/^(www)((\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(in|com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i";       
  $pattern_3 = "/^(([A-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)+.(co|in|com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i";
  $pattern_4 = "/^(([A-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)+.(co|in|com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se*)+.(co|in|com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i";
  if(preg_match($pattern_1, $val) || preg_match($pattern_2, $val) || preg_match($pattern_3, $val) || preg_match($pattern_4, $val)){
    return true;
  } else{
    return false;
  }
}

$url = "google.com.in";
echo validateURL($url); 
?>
```